# Por que o Retorno desse Script esta vindo vazio

Tags: powershell

#Conexão
$SqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

```
$SqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=$($SqlServer);Database=$($SqlDatabase);Uid=$($SqlUser);Pwd=$($SqlPass);Integrated Security=True"

$SqlConn.Open()

# Comando Select

$Sqlcmdread = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

$sqlcmdread.Connection = $SqlConn

$Sqlcmdread.CommandText = "select convert(char, max(convert(datetime , time,102)),121) time from JobLog "

# Executando

$Registro  = $Sqlcmdread.ExecuteReader()
```

o $Registro retorna :
RecordsAffected:-1  .
quando executo o select no sqlserver ele apresenta 1 registro. Aguem sabe o pq?

Answer (score 0):

O Método ExecuteReader() retorna um objeto SqlDataReader, então você deve acessar as propriedades do objeto para obter os valores. Pense como se objecto $Registro estivesse retornando uma tabela, logo você quer acessar a linha 1 da coluna 1:

```
    while($Registro.Read()){
        Write-Output $Registro.GetValue(0)
    }
```

Lembre-se de fechar o objeto $Registro

```
$Registro.Close()
```

Comment: Bom dia! 
Esta Apresentando esse Erro.
   Connection:Internal Error - System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed.
apos a instrução $Registro  = $Sqlcmdread.ExecuteReader()

Comment: Dá uma revisada no teu código, esse erro acontece quando voc6e tenta acessar um SqlDataReader mas a conexão já foi fechada. Nos meus testes tudo funciona bem. 
`$connectionString = ""
$SqlConn = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::new($connectionString)
$SqlConn.Open()
$Sqlcmdread = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlcmdread.Connection = $SqlConn
$Sqlcmdread.CommandText = "select convert(char, max(convert(datetime , getdate(),102)),121) time"
$Registro  = $Sqlcmdread.ExecuteReader()
while($Registro.Read()){
    Write-Output $Registro.GetValue(0)
}
$Registro.Close()`

Comment: OBRIGADOOOO!!!!                    mudei para o seu estilo de conexão e deu certo...

Comment: Que legal que funcionou. Poderia marcar a sua pergunta como respondida? Brigadão.

Comment: @user284942 - poderia marcar a sua pergunta como respondida?